# Find upper bound of an integral using the ML inequality. $\left| \int_{\Gamma} \ln (z+3) \right|$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I need to find an upper bound of  the following integral:

$$\left| \int_{\Gamma} \ln (z+3) \right|$$

Where $\Gamma$ is the line segment from

$(-1+3i)$  to $(4+3i)$.

We have:

$$\left| \int_{\Gamma} \ln (z+3) \right|~\leq ML$$

Finding L is easy, as it is just the distance between the given points, which in this this case is equal to:

$5$.

So:

$$\left| \int_{\Gamma} \ln (z+3) \right|~\leq 5M$$
Now, I'm a little lost when it comes to this:

$$ln(z+3)$$

I tried doing this:

$$ln(x+iy+3)$$

But I'm kinda lost as is not close to what the textbook I'm using has.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is the distance between the two points equal to $5$?

Comment: @angryavian
Made a mistake typing in the information. Points should be $(-1+3i)$  to $(4+3i)$, and using the general formula to find the distance, it is indeed $5$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$ \ln(z+3) = |z+3| + i \arg(z+3) $$

with $z = x + 3i$ where $-1 \le x \le 4$ or $2 \le x+3 \le 7$

Then

$$ |z+3|^2 = (x+3)^2 + 3^2 \le 7^2 + 3^2 = 58 $$

$$ \arg(z+3) = \arctan \frac{3}{x+3} \le \arctan\frac32 $$

Finally, you can make a bound

$$ |ln(z+3)| = \sqrt{|z+3|^2 + \arg^2(z+3)} \le \sqrt{58 + \arctan^2 \frac32} $$